# LIRC irsend: could not connect to socket irsend: No such file or directory

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2, lirc

I am trying to configure **LIRC** to work with my **Raspberry 2B** and a circuit I build with a transistor and a IR transmitter as explained in this [tutorial](http://www.raspberry-pi-geek.com/Archive/2015/10/Raspberry-Pi-IR-remote)

After the installation of LIRC, I followed all the steps and I added these two lines in */etc/modules*

```
lirc_dev
lirc_rpi gpio_out_pin=36
```

Then I typed this in /etc/lirc/hardware.conf

```
LIRCD_ARGS="--uinput"
LOAD_MODULES=true
DRIVER="default"
DEVICE="/dev/lirc0"
MODULES="lirc_rpi"
LIRCD_CONF=""
LIRCMD_CONF=""
```

After rebooting, I added the configuration of my Samsung remote (BN59-00516A) to */etc/lirc/lircd.conf*

Then I restarted LIRC again but when I run a command to send a IR frequency

```
irsend SEND_ONCE Samsung_BN59-00865A KEY_POWER
```

it complains with the following error:

> irsend: could not connect to socket
>
> irsend: No such file or directory

I am guessing this is a problem with my device socket, because in the hardware.conf file I set

```
DEVICE = "/dev/lirc0"
```

(just because the tutorial states it), but lirc0 file isn't within the folder. 
I couldn't find any other question related to this problem and google didn't help me much either. Does anyone have any hint on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After googling a lot, I found out an update is needed to have everything working properly. In my case I did:

```
apt-get update, apt-get upgrade, rpi-update
```

Also, as pointed out in this other [tutorial](http://alexba.in/blog/2013/01/06/setting-up-lirc-on-the-raspberrypi/), depending on the Raspberry firmware, you might need to add this to */boot/config.txt*

```
dtoverlay=lirc-rpi,gpio_in_pin=XX,gpio_out_pin=YY
```

Substitute X and Y for whatever pins you're using!

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem and I solved it with this command:

```
sudo lircd --device /dev/lirc0
```

If you set the value of LIRCD_ARGS in /etc/lirc/hardware.conf to "--device /dev/lirc0", it should start lircd appropriately, when /etc/init.d/lirc is started at boot.

Answer (score 1):

you need to run `lircd`. It will create two files (`lircd` and `lircd.pid`) at `/var/run/lirc/`:

```
lircd
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error messages. But had all configurations done. The restart of the lirc daemon solved this issue by typing 
$ sudo /etc/init.d/lirc restart

Comment: for me it was a: `sudo /etc/init.d/lircd restart`

Answer (score 0):

I think is useful to say that the `gpio_in_pin=XX,gpio_out_pin=YY` part of the `/etc/modules` can be double checked with
`dmesg | grep lirc`
which results in something like

```
[    3.437499] lirc_dev: IR Remote Control driver registered, major 244
[    5.472916] lirc_rpi: module is from the staging directory, the quality is unknown, you have been warned.
[    6.621156] lirc_rpi: auto-detected active high receiver on GPIO pin 22
[    6.622515] lirc_rpi lirc_rpi: lirc_dev: driver lirc_rpi registered at minor = 0
[    6.622528] lirc_rpi: driver registered!
```

for `/etc/modules` containing

```
lirc_dev
lirc_rpi gpio_in_pin=23 gpio_out_pin=22
```